# Open external Website with a custom header using Vaadin 7

Tags: http, redirect, header, vaadin

I am new in Vaadin7 and I need some help. I'm developing a very simple application where placed few button or redirect link. When the button or link is clicked, a new window opening and the external web site appear in that window. I do this that way :

```
Button button = new Button("Window", new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                getUI().getPage().open("http://www.myotherapplication.com", "_blank");
            }
        });
```

It is simple, and it is working well. My question is : How could I add some HTTP Headers to the request ? I need to transfer some basic informations, for example username, token and etc. Could anyone help me ? Are there any solution ? Thanks !

Comment: How about passing that information as GET parameters? http://www.myotherapplication.com?token=123&username=foobar

Comment: No, just as Request Headers, like Accept, Accept-Encoding, Cookie, etc. I want to add "Name:abc123" and "Token:jhgjhghgugug" headers.

Comment: The web app that responses to your http://www.myotherapplication.com request should add those headers there, a calling application cannot do that. Or is the application running at http://www.myotherapplication.com actually a Vaadin app?

Comment: I don't get you, But if I want to be more clearly the Vaadin web app is just a login app where users authenticate themselves and after choose an other independent app ( via redirect link ) and they will be redirect over there. The independent apps need a name and token in the request header in order to the users won't have to login again. Have you better idea ?

Comment: Ohhh, I got you, right now. I am wrong, that way basically is a big mistake and my question is so foolish... Maybe there is better way, for example the usage of the local storage. ( The Vaadin app has to store the token in the local storage and the others have to read up it and check. ) Thanks Henri !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a browser add headers for a page when redirecting the browser. The browser will choose to add its own headers.

Secondly, I recommend you create a Vaadin Link instead, not a Vaadin Button. A button click leading to a new window opening will be registered as a javascript window.open() and will get blocked by most modern browsers as a "popup".

A Vaadin Link will get rendered as an  tag. With this you can open a new window using the target attribute, which can be set on the Vaadin Link. This will most likely not get blocked as a popup.